# How to make sidebar collapse horizontal using css and angular-ui?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use collapse angular-ui directive to use slide functionality of sidebar , slide is working but `diagrams` button is staying at same position. How can i move `diagrams` button to right of cols when sidebar is visible and move to the left when when sidebar is slided in ? if i add `margin-left` `diagrams` button will move to right side of cols but it does not go back to left when sidebar is not visible.

**html**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="horizontal-collapse" uib-collapse="isCollapsed">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="position: static">
      <treecontrol class="tree-classic"
                   tree-model="dataForTheTree"
                   options="treeOptions"
                   on-selection="showSelected(node)"
                   selected-node="node1" id="treecontrol">

      <span  ng-click="importXMLFunction(node)">
        {{node.text}}
      </span>
      </treecontrol>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" id="treelist">diagrams</span>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#treelist{
  width:100px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  position:relative;
  top:70px;
  left:0px;

}
```

**JS**

```
$scope.isNavCollapsed = true;
$scope.isCollapsed = false;
$scope.isCollapsedHorizontal = false;
```